# UIButtons won't click in simulator swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I just can't find why the UIbuttons are not working. They were working for awhile. Not sure what happened.

```
import UIKit  

class ViewController: UIViewController 
{

@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = false

@IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!
    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber {
        display.text = display.text! + digit
    }
    else {
        display.text = digit
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = true
    }
}

var operandStack = Array<Double>()

@IBAction func enter() {
    userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = false
    operandStack.append(displayValue)
    println("operandStack = \(operandStack)")
}

var displayValue: Double {
    get {
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    }
    set {
        display.text = "\(newValue)"
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingNumber = false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

chances are that after having made the `IBAction connect` you would change the name of the function, which untying its storyboard to your `ViewController`, if this were the case consult the *storyboard* and unlink the above, then should link to new.

Also I suggest you check this out:

```
@IBAction func enter(sender: AnyObject) {}
```

**or**

```
@IBAction func enter(sender: UIButton!) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did triple check that before asking, and I just unlink and relink for the third time making sure it had the same func name.

I'm trying to build a calculator where appendDigit is coming from the "1..9" UIButtons and append to a display labeled "0".

Comment: I recommend for this type of behavior on your buttons dynamically generate code associating a `addTarget` with the same selector function.

Comment: Figured it out. My simulator wasn't working and was not allowing me to click on buttons for some reason. After quiting xcode and the simulator and restarting it worked. Weird.